# excel download using javascript blob is not formatted row wise

Tags: javascript, excel, formatting, blob

i have the data on the front end in the form of javascript object. now i need to push this into an excel and download it when the user clicks on a button.
i am using the below code,

```
 var blob = new Blob([ArrayOfData], {type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'});
 var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
 var a = document.createElement("a");
 a.style.display = "none"
 a.href = downloadUrl;
 a.download = "data.csv";
 document.body.appendChild(a);
 a.click();
```

Success part : data is being pushed into the excel and file is downloaded.

Failure : all the data is added in the same row, in different columns

Question : is it possible to add the data row by row, in same column?

`a.click();`

Comment: How do you actually generate the data? Are you sure `ArrayOfData` contains everything in the proper format?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `ArrayOfData` is a an array containing multiple arrays of values.

```
[
   [1, 33, 42, 13],
   ...
]
```

there is a simpler way to achieve this, such as:

```
var blob = new Blob([ArrayOfData.join('\n')], {type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'});
```

In a CSV columns are separated by using `,` and rows are separated using `\n` or new line (`<br>` in HTML). so we join all the sub-arrays using it.